# Loading page fragments that are search engine friendly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Sorry if this is a slightly general question.

I sometimes have to load page fragments from other pages within a website using jquery/ajax. There are a number of reason I need to do this, but I understand client side ajax content is invisible to search engines.

Is that correct? And if so, is there another way of doing this that is search engine friendly.

The sites are asp.NET, although I'll admit I'm not a .net expert.

Thanks.

Comment: [Google has been working on making AJAX content crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/), but you have to do some work yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I understand client side ajax content is invisible to search engines.
```

This is correct. Search engines like Google won't follow the AJAX cleanly.

---

Edit: Not true - it's possible with extra effort. See Blazemonger's comment on OP post.

---

To be search engine friendly, the content you want the search engines to index needs to be present in the page built by the server, previous to any Javascript or other client-side scripts adding content.

Are you able to load the page fragments on your server and build them into your page perhaps, before your page is rendered to the end user? This would be Google friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No unfortunately I can't build it like that. It's a bit of an odd setup, but the end game is to have a fragment of a page shared between a number of other pages. I didn't know if you could load page fragments server side somehow.

Comment: Nice find, blazemonger! Learning something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

To reuse HTML between multiple pages in .net, check out this OReily article:
http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_ReusableUI.html

If the reused content is from the same server, this is the best way to allow search engines to quickly find and users to navigate your site.